# How to use querySelector to find all external links with a specific class

Tags: javascript

I want to find out all external links (links that are not pointing to the current domain) within a specific class (.post-inner) but I cannot find out how to do it.
I think it could be achieved with querySelector (I am not using jQuery).
This is the current code which doesn't work:

```
function linkopener(a) {
var c = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i].hostname != window.location.hostname && c[i].protocol != 'tel:' && c[i].protocol != 'mailto:' && c[i].querySelector('.post-inner')) {
        c[i].target = '_blank';
        c[i].rel = 'noopener noreferrer';
        c[i].title = '\u00f6ffnet in neuem Fenster - ' + c[i].title;
        c[i].className += ' external-link'
     }
}
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your internal links are relative (do not start with "http://yourdomain.com/...")
You can use the `querySelector` to find all  tags that have a protocol specifier like this:

```
var aTags = document.body.querySelectorAll('.post-inner a[href*="://"]');
```

If the  tag has a "href" attribute that contains "://" and is inside an element with class "post-inner" it will be found.

Comment: Links are set absolutely

Comment: In that case you will have to loop through the found links and see if the domain part is equal to `window.location.hostname`

Comment: How would the whole code block look like in that case?
It doesn't work with this one:
    function linkopener(a) {
    var c = document.body.querySelectorAll('.post-inner a[href*="://"]'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].hostname != window.location.hostname && c[i].protocol != 'tel:' && c[i].protocol != 'mailto:') {
            c[i].target = '_blank';
            c[i].rel = 'noopener noreferrer';
            c[i].title = '\u00f6ffnet in neuem Fenster - ' + c[i].title;
            c[i].className += ' external-link'
         }
    }
};

Comment: The code you show looks ok to me, did you run it after the browsers 'DOMContentLoaded' event? You can always add the word `debugger;` after the `querySelectorAll` and open the Developer tools. The browser will break on the line of code. and you can inspect what the value of `c` is

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Not sure what went wrong first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this,

```
$(".post-inner>a[href^="http:"] ,.post-inner>a[href^="tel:"], ...")
```

Comment: I am not using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
c[i].classList.contains('post-inner')
```

instead

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. Maybe because the links are inside of a <p> without a class which is nested inside of the div with the class "post-inner"?